# Serving files from an Angular Application via the URL

Tags: angular

Trying to submit my application for a production API rate key and one of the steps is to upload a .txt file and make the file publicly accessible from

`https://myUrl/verification.txt`

Now I'm hosting my application with google cloud without the backend in place right now is there any feasibly way to achieve what is being asked without BE route in place to serve said file?

Comment: You can have that file in your src folder and copy it to root using the assets array in angular.json. That is how i do for the google verification file for example.

Comment: You my friend are a legend!